# C++ "Using" in Modules

Tags: c++, c++20

**One** of the reasons "using namespace" in header files is considered bad practise ([Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)) is because it "leaks" the using-directive to everyone that includes your headerfile. Is this still the case for C++ modules or can I "safely" put e.g. `using namespace std` or `using std::cout` into my module? :

```cpp
module;
#include <iostream>
export module Module;

using namespace std;
// using std::cout;
export void greet() {
    cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Comment: FWIW, another reason not to use `using namespace std;` is that it can cause problems in the header itself.  For something as short as adding `std::` to a standard library usage, it's still not worth using `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @NathanOliver `that it can cause problems in the header itself`, that reason would not be limited to headers but should be true for cpp files?

Comment: @t.niese It's true for all files.  `using namespace std;` likes to break all sorts of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope of any `using` declaration of this sort is the translation unit being compiled. All module files (a file that starts with some form of module declaration) is a separate translation unit. So it will be just like any other non-`export`ed declaration in your module: local to it.

*That having been said*, this is only one reason to avoid `using namespace std`; there are many others. It can play havoc with name lookup. The included names can clash with global names and names used in your namespace. And so forth.

However, employing `using` declarations for specific components of the `std` namespace is a lot more reasonable, as the primary reason not to do so is to prevent leakage. Also, `namespace` aliases are a good idea too, for sub-namespaces like `std::chrono`, `std::filesystem`, and the like.

Comment: Note that, unlike *using-declaration*s, you can’t export *using-directive*s in (the published) C++20 (although it’s conceivable that that could be considered a defect after the fact), except by having them in a header unit (where everything is).